# How to catch exception in main function, not in imported library

Tags: python, exception

I have a script file `main.py` that imports a class from `lib.py`, respectively:

```
#main.py
from lib import Example

try:
    ex = Example()
except ValueError:
    print("ValueError caught in main.py")
```

and

```
#lib.py
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        try:
            raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError caught in lib.py")
```

When I execute `main.py` the error printed is `"ValueError caught in lib.py"`, but I would like this error be caught in `main.py` as `"ValueError caught in main.py"`.

Why in `main.py` the `except` block doesn't catch the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the exception in the lib.py, so the exception stops at the last line you reported with the print.

You have 2 solutions:

1. catch twice the exception for some reason:

   ```
    def init(self):
        try:
            raise ValueError
        except ValueError as err:
            print("ValueError caught in lib.py")
            raise err
   ```
2. Catch only in the main.py

   ```
    def init(self):
        raise ValueError
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You raise and catch the ValueError in your lib file. If you want only main to catch it then delete the try\except in lib and leave the raise

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions propagate up the call chain in Python. The innermost except that matches will always be the one to handle the error. If you don't want the error to be caught in lib.py, then just use

```
#lib.py
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init()

    def init(self):
       raise ValueError
```